# cut command behaving differently when its output is " * "

Tags: shell-script, grep, cut

I am trying to create a shell script, below is a part of which where i am trying to extract some value from a record in a file:

```
tgt_val=`cat $file_name | grep "$string_name" | cut -d"|" -f$column_no`
```

This work perfectly when the specified column has some numeric or string value however it fails when th column has value as " * "

eg:

```
102|Sam|*|USA
```

This command would work correctly for column 1,2 & 4

However in case of column 3 it gives me output as all the files in present directory.

Someone please help over this.

Comment: [Quote your variables!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766). Use `printf '%s\n' "$tgt_val"`, not `echo $tgt_val` (same for those `$file_name` and `$column_no` that you forgot to quote). See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that somehow the `*` is being interpreted by the shell. Make sure all extracted fields are always properly quoted.